# How to enable POST method on heroku server (for React app)? I am getting 405 method not allowed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am getting 405 method not allowed. I am using axios.post for login. 
The form is taking input username and password and post to get authenticate.
But POST method not allowed at heroku error in console.

Please help me to let me know how to enable POST method on heroku. or any solution.

Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CYDF.png)

Comment: Cors  problem, what backend type you  are  using  ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an axios post example:

```
axios.post("test/test", {userName:'..', password:'..'}).then((result) => onSuccess(result.data), (error) => onError(error));
```

If you are using spring-boot with Java you probably have a CORS problem. Try to put in your endpoint:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000", "url2", "url3})
```

Replace "http://localhost:3000" with your localhost url if you need it. This is an example:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000", "url2", "url3})
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> testLoginUser(@RequestBody DTO testDto) throws TestException {

     //Do Something..
}
```

I don't know how the server is implemented, so: check if you have a CrossOrigin problem or if you have a security problem with your endpoints.

Comment: I am using MERN stack on heroku

Comment: Check if you have problems on ports (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591374/mern-stack-express-and-react-on-same-port).

At the end: ensure your server.js is running correctly and ensure that you don't have cross origin problems (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue)

Ensure you have done all the necessary steps: https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-with-heroku/

Another good link: https://hashnode.com/post/react-tutorial-using-mern-stack-ciiyus9m700qqge53mer0isxz

Comment: App is on heroku server. I have contacted support and they replied:

"The create-react-app-buildpack uses the heroku/static buildpack which in turn uses a nginx web server. Unfortunately nginx does not allow POST calls from static pages. You will need to make a GET request here."

Comment: So, I think that you cannot edit the nginx.conf file because only Heroku can edit it. Check if you can do something like this: https://m.alphasights.com/using-nginx-on-heroku-to-serve-single-page-apps-and-avoid-cors-5d013b171a45